# After pasting an array, I want to paste a new array next to the first one

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-2010, vba

I have this automatic procedure that works great

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A, L:L")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo Fìn
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim arrmatrix As Variant
    ReDim arrmatrix(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 12).Value = "Pi emitida" Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrmatrix(1 To 1, 1 To n)
            arrmatrix(1, n) = Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
    With Worksheets("Inicio")
        .Range("G4:G" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
        .Range("G4").Resize(UBound(arrmatrix, 2), 1) =      Application.Transpose(arrmatrix)
    End With
End If
Fìn:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

My problem now is that I want to do the same and paste a different array in the colum next to the first one, the array must do the same but if these conditions are achieved:

```
dim hoy as date
hoy=date
If Cells(j, 12).Value = "Pi emitida" Or Cells(j, 12).Value = "PI firmada" Or       Cells(j, 12).Value = "Carta credito L/c" Or Cells(j, 12).Value = "Con booking" And hoy - Cells(j, 12).Value >= 0
```

Comment: my mistake, it was macros

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, Dim j As Long, m As Long
    Dim arrmatrix() As Variant, Dim arrmatrix1() As Variant
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A, L:L")) Is Nothing Then
    ' On Error GoTo Fìn 'Commented to find out which line your error actually is - Uncomment once fixed
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 12).Value = "Pi emitida" Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrmatrix(1 To 1, 1 To n)
            arrmatrix(1, n) = Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If

        If (Cells(i, 12).Value = "Pi emitida" Or Cells(i, 12).Value = "PI firmada" Or Cells(i, 12).Value = "Carta credito L/c" Or Cells(i, 12).Value = "Con booking") and DateDiff(d, Cells(i, 17).Value, Today) > 0 Then
            m = m + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrmatrix1(1 To 1, 1 To m)
            arrmatrix1(1, m) = Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
    With Worksheets("Inicio")
        .Range("G4:G" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
        .Range("G4").Resize(UBound(arrmatrix, 2), 1) = Application.Transpose(arrmatrix)
        .Range("H4:H" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
        .Range("H4").Resize(UBound(arrmatrix1, 2), 1) = Application.Transpose(arrmatrix1)
    End With
End If

 Fìn:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```